# converting ASCII char array to hex char array

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to convert an ASCII char array to hex char array to do something like this:

Input :  `char string[5]="abcd1234567"`

Output : `char buf[4096] = {0x63, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37};`

but my code didn't work and i couldn't figure it out.

code:

```
char string[20]="abcd";
   char buff[4000];
   

    sprintf(buff[0],"%02x",string[0]);

    printf("string[0]: %c",string[0]);
```

it gives this error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   16 |     sprintf(buff[0],"%02x",string[0]);
```

Comment: Hint: it's already in that format.

Comment: It appears to only be a warning and not an error

Comment: First argument to `sprintf` needs to be `buff` not `buff[0]`....

Comment: @Noah: It's a compiler error on any decent compiler and a runtime error even if the compiler improperly downgrades it to a warning.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah that makes sense, my bad

Comment: `string[5]` is too short

Comment: Decimal, hexadecimal, or even printable character, it's all just how the underlying binary value is presented. Try e.g. `printf("0x%02x\n", string[0]);` to see what you get.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  The C++ language has a `std::string` type so you don't need to mess with character arrays.  Adjust your tags accordingly

Comment: Your output in the first example is wrong.  The output shows `'c`' as the first item in the string (0x63).

Comment: It would be easier if you output directly with `printf()` and skip the string-building part.

Comment: Re "*Which language, C or C++?*", Going to assume C and remove the C++ tag. Feel free correct.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between `(char)'a'` and `(char)0x61` on an ASCII-based machine, so all you need is the following:

```c
char buf[4096];
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
strncpy(buf, string, sizeof(buf));
```

The `memset` sets the trailing elements to `0` just like `char buf[4096] = { ... };` would. You can get rid of it if you don't care about the trailing elements.

The `strncpy` does the following:

```c
buf[ 0] = string[ 0];  // 'a'  0x61
buf[ 1] = string[ 1];  // 'b'  0x62
...
buf[11] = string[11];  // '7'  0x37
buf[12] = string[12];  // '\0' 0x00
```

Note the trailing NUL being copied. But that's inconsequential given the extra room in `buf`. Use `memcpy` instead of `strncpy` if you want to avoid that extra NUL.

Comment: I assumed the OP wants to output a complete array definition *as text* (to paste into another program).

Comment: Do you also think char `string[5]="abcd1234567"` is C code to parse?

Comment: No, I think "Output : `char buf[4096] = {0x63, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37};`" is.

Comment: @Weather Vane, I find it less likely that two different notations are used for the input and output, and more likely that the OP doesn't know they're already the same bytes.